# SQL number of patients in hospital each day

Tags: sql, count, days

I’m trying to calculate the number of patients in hospital each day in a given period, eg: April 2018 based on the admission data and the discharge date. So for example,

```
Patient ID  Admission date  Discharge date
A   25-Apr-18   25-Apr-18
B   25-Apr-18   26-Apr-18
C   26-Apr-18   28-Apr-18
D   29-Apr-18   01-May-18
```

Would yield the following:

```
Date    Bed days
25-Apr-18   2
26-Apr-18   2
27-Apr-18   1
28-Apr-18   1
29-Apr-18   1
30-Apr-18   1
```

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome Jim! To better help you, we would like to see the current tables, some sample data, what you expect, your current SQL, and what type of SQL you are working with (SQL Server, PostGres, MySQL, etc).

Comment: As an aside, creating a dimension table that contains all dates; it makes these types of queries much easier because you can join to it to get dates that are in the span of a given set of dates. This is not the only way of course, but is the most re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server your code would be something close to:

```
SELECT PatientID
       ,DATEDIFF(DAY, [AdmissionDate], [DischargeDate]) AS [Bed Days]
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY [PatientID]
```

Which would return the count of PatientID for each day. However, without more information such as database type/version, or an easy-to-read preferred output it'll be more difficult to get you the kind of results you want.

Comment: Doesn't take discharge date into account

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't read the code he posted, therefor I couldn't see the discharge date field. I'll update the my answer in a few minutes once it's revised.

Answer (score 0):

There's a strategic level problem you have to figure out how you want to solve: what drives the dates?  In other words, you've got your "desired result" table - how does it get the dates in the left hand side?

That might seem like a silly/stupid question, but imagine you had two rows in your table:

```
1/1/2018 through 1/3/2018
2/1/2018 through 2/3/2018
```

... well, your report *should* have all the days between 1/4 and 1/31 which had '0' patients, right?  So realistically, you're either going to have to loop through a date range and generate each date, or have a master "ListOfEveryDate" table (as UnhandledExcepSean suggested in his comment.)  And if you want to loop through a date range, are you going to have that loop occur in SQL or in a higher-level language like .NET?

Personally, I'd just go with the MasterDateTable idea, even though it's a bit clunky, simply for how simple it is at the code level:

```
select
    date,
    (select subquery to get count of records in data table)
from
    masterDateTable
where date between @startDate and @endDate
```

... and as long as you have code that makes sure you keep the table populated with dates, you're good (you'd hate for the code to stop working because you only populated it through the year 2020, but it turns out it's still being used in 2021!)